# PostgreSQL - Is it possible to port pg_large_object data to bytea column within same database schema

Tags: postgresql

In Java application, I used Hibernate @Lob for storing large content (files, images, xml content, etc.) in PostgreSQL 9.x. Hibernate automatically stores the said content into pg_large_object table. However during update operation of database tables which references pg_large_object table, it causes a duplicate copy of the same data added into pg_large_object. The old references of the same data (in pg_large_object) were abandoned. This is a side effect of using pg_large_object even though I don't update the large content. This behavior increases the size of the database without owner's knowledge. I already knew that we can use VACCUM configuration ON in database to clean-up abandoned data. But to avoid this situation, we changed our java code, means changed the data-type for the said column as BYTEA instead of Large Object (if we remove @Lob declaration from hibernate entity, it will be automatically mapped as bytea type).

Now the question is the backward compatibility. If we change the data-type of a column in existing table, how to migrate or port the existing production data into new data-type for the above scenario.? Thanks in advance for your feedback.